# Problem installing PyDev and SDK installation in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, sdk

I was trying to install PyDev and SDK in Eclipse, and I got this error:

```
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException
Unable to read repository at http://pydev.org/updates/content.xml
```

Comment: the possible reason of the error is it cant update it from the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following setting and you will be all set.
Go to Window --> Preference --> General --> Network Connection --> select Direct from drop down!

[image: Your should be similar to this]

here check for any wrong proxy entry- means you dont have any *local or  set to native provider in `Proxy bypass` also make sure not to have any other HTTP in proxy entries seted to native.

thats all.

Comment: Its working but installation stops at 26%...I waited for 2 hours but it shows 26%...

Comment: abort it ... after a soft restart try.. if it succeed then lemmme know .. i will mention the command for removing broken downloads ..

Comment: and check your internet connection before doing any further.. this could take time ..in my case it has taken around 5 hours as I am getting only 60kbps of downloading speed  .

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below link

```
http://update-production-pydev.s3.amazonaws.com/pydev/updates/site.xml
```

instead of

```
http://pydev.org/updates
```